# Перенос слова в конец поля

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/v085f7up/

Как перенести слово "**Забыли?**" в конец поля?

Приблизительный подбор `margin-left` не устраивает. Нужно нормальное решение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно добавить `right:0`

```
#last_password {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -19px;
    right: 0;
}
```

[Ваш пример](http://jsfiddle.net/v085f7up/1/)

UPD. [[@ModaL](/users/6646/modal)](/users/6646/modal), а чтобы не сносило вправо, нужен контейнер с заданной шириной, который будет оборачивать оба элемента. У вас же ширина `450px`, вот [обновлённый пример](http://jsfiddle.net/v085f7up/3/)

Comment: Ваш пример тупо в самое право документа сносит текст. Измените ширину поля на 250px и посмотрите...

Comment: @ModaL, обновил пример, также теперь можно не использовать отрицательный margin, а сделать просто top:0

Comment: Отлично, то что нужно. Спасибо :)